# Explain confusion about the identity $\lim \inf x_n = \lim \inf A_n$, with $A_n = \{x_k | k \ge n\}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am confused about one thing during the lecture.

Let $x_n = n$ and  $A_n = \{x_k | k \ge n\} = \{n, n+1, n+2, ...\}$.

Then, $\inf A_n = n $, and $\sup A_n = \infty$.

My lecturer also said that $\lim\inf x_n = \lim\inf A _n=\lim n$.

My thinking is that $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}=\{1, 2, 3, .....\}$. Shouldn't $\inf x_n = 1$?? Then, $\lim \inf x_n =1$, which is not equal to $\lim n$.

Could you tell me if I am wrong?

Comment: The statement is that $$\liminf_{n\to\infty} x_n = \lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\inf A _n\right)$$ with a liminf on the LHS and a (true) limit on the RHS. Does this explain things?

Comment: By definition $$\liminf_n x_n:=\sup_n(\inf_{k\ge n}x_n).$$
For the case of sets $(A_n)$, it is meant
$$
\liminf_n A_n:=\bigcup_n\left(\bigcap_{k\ge n}A_n\right).
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because we define $\liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_{n}=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\inf\limits_{k\geq n}x_{k}\right)=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\inf A_n\right)$.

It is not defined as $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\inf\{x_{k}:k=1,2,...\}$. Note that $\inf\{x_{k}: k=1,2,...\}$ is an extended real number independent of $n$, hence $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\inf\{x_{k}: k=1,2,...\}$ is simply $\inf\{x_{k}: k=1,2,...\}$.

@Did has noted a good comment.

Comment: Even more crucially, $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\inf\{x_{n}: n=1,2,...\}$$ is prone to misinterpretations and should be written $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\inf\{x_k:k=1,2,...\}$$

Comment: So, do you mean that $\lim \inf x_n = \lim \inf A_n$ is definition, and then since $ \lim \inf A_n = \lim n$, then $\lim \inf x_n$ must be equal to $\lim n$??

Comment: Yes, and then the $\liminf$ is equal to $\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed strange since we usually define$$\liminf_{n\to\infty} A_n = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \left(\bigcap_{k=n}^\infty A_n\right)$$

which is clearly a set.

It can be shown that

$$\liminf_{n\to\infty} A_n = \{x \in \mathbb{R} : x \in A_n \text{ for all except finitely many } n \in \mathbb{N}\}$$

so in this case we have $$\liminf_{n\to\infty} A_n = \emptyset$$

---

Another interpretation is $$\lim_{n\to\infty}( \inf A_n) = \lim_{n\to\infty} n = \lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = \liminf_{n\to\infty} x_n = +\infty$$

since $\inf A_n = n = x_n$, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$.